# Concatenate char* without using standard libraries and strings

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I need to implement a method that concatenates different characters into a char* without using any standard library (it's part of the specifications). So, no strcat or strcopy. I can't use strings neither.

Here's what I tried to do (the chars are stored in a StringList I implemented myself, hence the "GetCell" method and the ->next pointer) :

```
  char* IntlFinder::ConcatenateSrc ( int nSource, long beginPosition )
        char* res = new char;
        Cell* cell = ComList.GetCell(beginPosition);
        for (long i = beginPosition; i <= (CountTab[nSource]); i++)
        {
            if (nSource == 0 || cell->elem.source == nSource)
            {
                res[i-beginPosition] = cell->elem.caractere;
            }
            cell = cell->next;
        }

        *res = '\0';
        return res;
    }
```

When I'm debugging, this looks great until I get to a certain char, and then it bugs for no reason (the cell it's pointing to at that moment looks normal, with a valid adress).

Any thoughts on that?

--

EDIT: I tried to do this instead:

```
    for (long i = beginPosition; i <= (CountTab[nSource]-1); i++)
    {
        if (nSource == 0 || cell->elem.source == nSource)
        {
            *res = cell->elem.caractere;
            ++res = new char;
        }
        cell = cell->next;
    }
```

Which is supposed to increment the pointer and allocate memory (so I can add another value at the next iteration), and I don't have any SIGSERV error anymore.
But when I return this pointer or the original value of the pointer, poiting to the first char, I get nothing (in the first case) or just the first character (in the second case).

I didn't forget to add '\0' at the end, but this still doesn't make it a string.

Comment: Here's a hint: `char* res = new char;`

Comment: Your buffer isn't big enough... when it fails you have a valid address for whatever is following the buffer in memory.

Comment: I'm not sure I can give a "big enough" buffer: This string can range from 0 char to 10⁷ chars.
(or maybe I didn't understand well the concept of "buffer" here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
char * concat(char dest[], char src[])
{
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   while (dest[i]) ++i;
   while (src[j]) dest[i++] = src[j++];
   dest[i] = '\0';
   return dest;
}
```

Provided that `dest` is big enough to carry both itselt and `src`. Otherwise, this may cause unexpected results because of writing outside the bounds of array.

**ADD**

```
int main()
{
    char * buf = new char[1 << 30]; // allocate 2^30 = 1e9+ chars (very huge size)
    // you can use char buf[1 << 30];
    // which is faster and not needing to be released manually
    char tmp[] = "First portion";
    char tmp2[] = "Second porition";
    buf[0] = '\0'; // so that concat begins copying at 0
    concat(buf, tmp);
    // buf == "First portion"
    concat(buf, tmp2);
    // buf = "First portionSecond portion"

    ....
    // don't forget to release memory after you have finished
    delete[] buf;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly my problem: I need dynamic memory allocation because I don't know the exact destination size (depends on a lot of factors).

Isn't it possible to just concatenate chars without knowing the (approximate) size of the final string ?

Comment: No. You MUST know the size. Even std::string does so (as it depends on c-strings). You can't use liked list, you have always to use an array (which has a fixed size). I suggest approximating the maximal size by choocing a very big integer that will be always greater than input AND less that `2 * INT_MAX + 1` (i.e. max size cannot exceed `unsigned int`)

Comment: Mmh.

My Class must manage up to 10⁷ chars (so that's out of int's range, right ?).

Actually, I managed to allocate memory as I was adding chars. I'm only having problems returning the whole array of chars now.
(as far as my understanding of char* goes, it's only a succession of characters in the memory, and the variable is pointing to the first of those characters)

I did that, but when I return the original value of the pointer (edited the code at the top) I only get the first value... not the whole string.

Comment: No :) 10^7 is not out of range. INT_MAX is 2^31 - 1 which is greater than 2x10^9. And yes, `dist` is just a pointer. You don't even have to store `concat` return value, since the function modifies the array itslef.

Comment: The problem is, why is it even called "dynamic allocation" if I allocate memory for 10^7 chars each time? :/ I'm missing something here. (I'm still new to C++ and dynamic allocation, hence all the confusion). And can't I keep it a char* instead of using char[] ?

Comment: I have edited the answer. You are attempting to dynamic allocate an array with `char *b = new char`, while this allocates only one char.

Comment: OK. Thank you for the edit, It works, and even works for the exact size of the string (actually, It didn't work before when I did that because I forgot the +1 for the extra '\0' at the end).

Thank you !